# PHP not getting POST information

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to get user feedback emailed to me using the PHP `mail()` function. Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return false" name="form">
<table>   


<tr>
<td>Your email:</td> <td><input required type="text" name="youremail" placeholder="email@email.com"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Your message: </td><td><textarea rows="30" cols="40" name="message" style="vertical-align:top;"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>


<?php

$to = "email@email.com";

$message = $_POST["message"];

mail($to, 'Feedback', $message);

?>
```

The message is sent, but there is nothing in the body of the email. I've tested it, and it doesn't work.

Comment: You are sending the form every time your page loads.

Comment: Hint: [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: So I just need to put in something like `if(isset($_POST['submit']){ });`?

Comment: That is a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your error logging on, you will see this:

> Notice: Undefined index: message in xxxx on line 22

Also you're not sending the form: `onsubmit="return false"`

Make sure to check if variables are set also, with the `isset()` function.

Answer (score 2):

As said. Your page is sending empty information as soon as the page is loaded.

Therefore, using `isset()` and `empty()` are best to be used.

While making sure the message isn't left empty and using both conditions:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['message'])){

// ...

}
```

You should also use proper mail headers, otherwise many systems will recognize mail as spam without a `From:`

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

> *Failing to do this will result in an error message similar to Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing. The From header sets also Return-Path under Windows.*

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must submit the form. 
Then you can check if a variable exists and to run script.

Try

```
if(isset($_POST["message"])){
  $to = "email@email.com";
  $message = $_POST["message"];
  mail($to, 'Feedback', $message);
}
```

Delete onsubmit="return false"
With onsubmit="return false" the form can not be sent.

```
<form method="post" action="#" name="form">
<table>   


<tr>
<td>Your email:</td> <td><input required type="text" name="youremail" placeholder="email@email.com"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Your message: </td><td><textarea rows="30" cols="40" name="message" style="vertical-align:top;"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try" this. Adding an explanation will result in a better answer and may gain you IIP's

Comment: @JayBlanchard Just look at those teeth, *eh Sam?*

Comment: Actually, using the `submit` button would work better.

Comment: Bobby Darin would be proud *Ralph*. @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it is a POST:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
         $to = "email@email.com";

         $message = $_POST["message"];

         mail($to, 'Feedback', $message);
    } 
?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" name="form">

    <table>   


    <tr>
    <td>Your email:</td> <td><input required type="text" name="youremail" placeholder="email@email.com"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Your message: </td><td><textarea rows="30" cols="40" name="message" style="vertical-align:top;"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```